# Solve system of 5 unknowns and 5 nonlinear equations

Tags: equation-solving, functions, nonlinear, parametric-functions, system

I attached below the system of 5 equations that I am not able to solve using FindRoot. I also tried without defining the equations as functions but It didn't work.
`

```
eq1[Hb_, Db_] := Hb/Db == K;
eq2[Ks_, kb_, Db_, Gb_] := Ks == Sqrt[(Coth[kb Db])/(1 + Gb)];
eq3[Gb_, kb_, Db_] := Gb == (2 kb Db)/(Sinh[2 kb Db]);
eq4[Hb_, Ks_] := Hb/Ho == Ks;
eq5[Hb_, Gb_, kb_, Db_] := (Ho)^2 == Hb^2 (1 + Gb) Tanh[kb Db];

FindRoot[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, 
  eq5}, {{Hb, 6}, {Db, 8}, {kb, 0.01}, {Ks, 1}, {Gb, 10}}]`
```

Comment: A function needs arguments to evaluate: E.g.:eq1 is not a function call. Further, Ho has no value, therefore you can not use a numerical routine.

Comment: We need the values of `Ho`and `K`

Answer (score 1):

The equations depend on the variables `Hb  , Db  , kb , Ks , Gb` and two parameters `K,Ho`

For given parameters (examplary {K -> 1, Ho -> 1})  `NMinimize` might solve your problem:

```
eqn = {Hb/Db == K,Ks == Sqrt[(Coth[kb Db])/(1 + Gb)],Gb == (2 kb Db)/(Sinh[2 kb Db]) Hb/Ho == Ks (Ho)^2 == Hb^2 (1 + Gb) Tanh[kb Db]}

NMinimize[{1, eqn} /. {K -> 1, Ho -> 1}, {Hb  , Db  , kb , Ks , Gb }]
(*{1., {Hb -> 0.987152, Db -> 0.987152, kb -> 3.00016, Ks -> 0.987152, Gb -> 0.0317076}}*)
```